# UriComponentsBuilder - how to replace some of the queryParams and remove the unused?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, resttemplate

Hey i have this url that contains multiple query params - it is used for search. It's a hatehoas link

```
https://someurl/customers?customer-id={customer-id}&type={type}&something={something}
```

And i wish to replace only two of the the params

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("customer-id", customerId);
    params.put("something", something)

    UriComponents customerUrl = UriComponentsBuilder
          .fromHttpUrl(specialURL)
          .buildAndExpand(params).encode();
```

But this throws.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Map has no value for 'type'
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$MapTemplateVariables.getValue(UriComponents.java:346) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
```

What is the best workaround here, let's say I have around 7 params, replacing them by an empty string or cutting string in half seems rather hacky.

Comment: It's internal implementation is expecting all the key must be present in in params, otherwise you will get this exception.

Comment: You may want to parse the query string of special URL and put it in a map. Now you now know the url without query . You know what you want to send so you can use two approach here.
1) Either append only params which are present in the URL to encode.
2) always instantiate the full map( all non required field as blank/null/empty(what ever work) and rest with some value) . Then you can pass that map in uri component builder.

Comment: People that would like to remove _all_ query parameters can do: `builder.replaceQuery("")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UriComponents** is always expect all the key data must be present in the map, below is the code which is used by UriComponents which throws the exception.

```
@Override
public Object getValue(String name) {
    if (!this.uriVariables.containsKey(name)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Map has no value for '" + name + "'");
    }
    return this.uriVariables.get(name);
}
```

**Solution:**

So to solve your problem you can try following code.

```
class Param extends HashMap<String, String>{


    @Override
    public String get(Object key) {
        if(!super.containsKey(key)){
            super.put(key.toString(), "");
        }
        return super.getOrDefault(key, "t");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object arg0) {
        return true;
    }   
}

public class UriComponenet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Param params = new Param();
        params.put("customer-id", "1");
        String specialURL="https://someurl/customers?customer-id={customer-id}&type={type}&something={something}";
        UriComponents customerUrl = UriComponentsBuilder
              .fromHttpUrl(specialURL)
              .buildAndExpand(params).encode();

        System.out.println(customerUrl);        
    }
}
```

I have extends the HashMap class to Param and then use that class as an input to **buildAndExpand** method.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hmm, why is the default value "t"? This does solve problem of not throwing, but it looks as if my api design is not workign as it should. No response is given.

Comment: It is just a mistake, now you don't need even that **getOrDetault** method you can directly use **get** method now.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static <T> UriComponents removeQueryParams(URI uri, Set<T> removeThese) {

    UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder
        .newInstance()
        .scheme(uri.getScheme())
        .schemeSpecificPart(uri.getSchemeSpecificPart())
        .userInfo(uri.getUserInfo())
        .host(uri.getHost())
        .port(uri.getPort())
        .path(uri.getPath())
        .fragment(uri.getFragment());

    UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromUri(uri).build();

    MultiValueMap<String, String> args = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(uriComponents.getQueryParams());
    removeThese.forEach(o -> args.remove(o.toString()));

    return uriComponentsBuilder
        .queryParams(args).build();
}
```